# How to decode an image so it can be feed into a keras model?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, keras

I have one image. I really want to transform/decode it to become a tensor.   Why? Because I want to feed this tensor into my neural network written in keras. The question is, how do I transform this image into a tensor with values, that doesn't give me an error when feeding the neural net ?

So suppose there is a PATH, and this has to be changed into a TENSOR, which can be feed into the keras neural network.

Thank you, very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Keras' `ImageDataGenerator()`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), which generates batches of tensor image data. You can then call `flow_from_directory()` on your `ImageDataGenerator()` object, which takes a path to the directory where your images are, and generates batches of data from the images themselves. These two videos demonstrate this process with an example:

- [Image preparation for CNN training with Keras](https://youtu.be/daovGOlMbT4)
- [Create and train a CNN with Keras](https://youtu.be/LhEMXbjGV_4)